# MySql query: get all customers that has their ID in both Customer and Customer_x_Billing table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am using a C# console app to get some data from a MySql database and I have some problems getting a query right

As it is now:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Customer_x_Billing c WHERE Customer.`customer id` = c.customer_id)
AND 2011 -04 -03 < ( SELECT last_changed FROM Customer_x_Billing c WHERE Customer.`customer id` = c.customer_id )
ORDER BY Customer.`customer id`
```

How can I improve this one?
I want to get all customers that has their ID in both Customer and Customer_x_Billing table and where the last_changed date in Customer_x_Billing is greater than a parameter (2011-04-03 in this case). If I set the date to 2012-04-03 it shouldn't return any row but it returns all records that match the first condition (exist in both).

Comment: Without analysing your query much, the most obvious issue with your query is the way you have specified the date parameter. What you've got there is interpreted as an arithmetic expression, `2011 - 04 - 03`, which is evaluated accordingly and then implicitly converted to the date/time value when comparing to the result of the subquery. In order for the parameter to be interpreted as a date, you need to enclose it in single quotes, just like most of the answers suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
INNER JOIN
Customer_x_Billing ON Customer.`customer id` = Customer.customer_id
WHERE last_changed > 2011 -04 -03
ORDER BY Customer.`customer id`
```

problem with you query is you are scanning Customer_x_Billing table two time which is not needed, its better to go for one inner join which will stisfy you first condition the exists one and second satisfy by writing the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT c.* FROM Customer c INNER JOIN Customer_x_Billing cb ON cb.customer_id = c.id WHERE DATE(cb.last_changed) > '2011-04-03' ORDER BY c.id;`

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right I belive you can achieve this with an INNER JOIN...

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Customer_x_Billing b
    ON c.customer_id = b.customer_id
WHERE last_changed_date > '2011-04-03'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer.* FROM Customer c INNER JOIN Customer_x_Billing b
ON c.`customer id`=b.`customer id`
WHERE last_changed>'2011-04-03'
ORDER BY c.`customer id`
```

Anyway beware of dates in your query...

Answer (score 0):

More or less like this.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
  {
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText 
      = "SELECT * FROM Custromer c JOIN Customer_x_Billing cb ON c.'customer id' = cd.'customer id' Where last_change < @lastChangeDate";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastChangeDate",  new DateTime(2011,04,03));
    using (SqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (drd.Read())
      {
        // Read from data reader
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For sake of your application you should get familiar with some database tutorial, and try to understand the concept of relational databases.